# UIScrollView needs to get bigger every time I add a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

The scrollView is created in my storyboard and is horizontal. Here is the method where I add a button for every loop and need to increase the size of the scrollView every time a button is added.

```
- (void) populateGroups {
    NSInteger x = [self.groupNameArray count];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        NSString *name = [self.groupNameArray objectAtIndex:i];

        // Create Button
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(count, 0, 100, 54)];
        [button setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        [button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        [button.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(groupPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i;
        [self.groupScrollView addSubview:button];
        count = count + 100;

       // Increase ScrollViewSize
        self.groupScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameWidth, 80);
        frameWidth = frameWidth + 100;
    }
}
```

The scrollView stays the same when I try to add two buttons to the view.

Comment: If x is ever big (say > 10), you might want to consider using a collection view instead of a scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

you have to increase the content size of the scroll view like:

```
self.groupScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frameWidth, 80);
```

and better to do it after the loop.